# Closure of a Hilbert subset with respect to a norm not defined on the entire Hilbert space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, unbounded-operators

I have some problems to understand the definition of the closure of an operator.

Let's $H$ be a Hilbert space with the norm $||\cdot||_H$, and let $A$ be a linear and symmetric operator defined on the set $D(A) \subset H$, $A\colon D(A) \rightarrow H$.
On $D(A)$ we define the norm 
$$||x||_A = ||Ax||_H + ||x||_H, \forall\, x \in D(A) \subset H$$
Now, we define the closure of the operator $A$ (and we denote it by $\bar A$) as the extension of $A$ in the set $\overline{D(A)}^{||\cdot||_A}$, i.e.:
$$\bar A \colon \, \overline{D(A)}^{||\cdot||_A} \rightarrow H$$
and 
$$Ax = \bar A x, \forall \, x \in D(A)$$

**My problem is**: how can $\overline{D(A)}^{||\cdot||_A}$ be well-defined? By definition, such a set contains every $x \in H$ that can be approximated by a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset D(A)$ through the norm $||\cdot||_A$, i.e. every $x$ such that exists a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset D(A)$ and such that $||x_n - x||_A \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. However, $x_n-x$ is not in $D(A)$ in general, and $||\cdot||_A$ is only defined on $D(A)$.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I think what you are doing is not taking the *closure* of $D(A)$, but rather the *completion* of $D(A)$ with respect to the norm $\|\cdot\|_A$.

Comment: I think you are right, I got confused by the notations. Thanks!